# Pass the value from email to a content block using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, email-template, content-builder

In my email, I am calling a Content Block. The content block uses a lookup to pull out content from a Data Extension.

Example code in content block:

```
set @SourceDE                = "DE_NAME"             
set @subjectLine             = Lookup(@SourceDE,"subl","locale",@locale)

..........similarly pulls out other content like pre-header, header text etc. from SourceDE
```

I call this block from my email. This method works perfectly.

But what I want now is that I should be able to change the source DE in email and not in Content Block. Then from the email the source DE should  be dynamically set in Content Block.

**expected outcome**

In email

```
 set @SourceDE                = "NEW_DE_NAME"
```

In content block

```
 set @subjectLine             = Lookup(@SourceDE,"subl","locale",@locale)
```

Content block should fetch the Data Extension name from the email

So by doing this I can change the name of the source DE directly in the email & also re-use the content block for other emails.

Please can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampscript gets evaluated top to bottom. So any declaration of variable further down in your code (whether it is within the email itself, or in a referenced content block) will always overwrite any declarations of same variable further up in your code.

How I would do this, to make this more robust, is to check if `@sourceDE` is already declared, when looking it up in your content block. So:

---

**In email:**

```
SET @sourceDE = "NEW_DE_NAME"
```

---

**In content block:**

```
IF EMPTY(@sourceDE) THEN
SET @sourceDE = "FALLBACK_DE_NAME"
ENDIF
SET @subjectLine = LOOKUP(@SourceDE,"subl","locale",@locale)
```

---

In this case, you will only set the DE name in content block if it for some reason gets included in an email without an existing declaration of `@sourceDE`. Otherwise it will take the `@sourceDE` value set in the email, before the content block is referenced.